# check multiple variable cannot be same

Tags: php

I have multiple variables. I want to check if one variable can not be same as other. This is my code, can you help me to make it simple?

```
<?php
$a = $_POST["a"];
$b = $_POST["b"];
$c = $_POST["c"];
$d = $_POST["d"];

if ($a == $b || $a == $c || $a == $d || $b == $c || $b == $d || $c == $d) {
    echo "variable cannot be same";
} else {
    echo "good";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of extracting the variables from the POST array, you can just use them from where they are.
Use [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to count how many of each value there is in the array.
Then use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to remove all that is count 1, meaning unique.
If there is something left in the array then there are duplicates.

```
if(array_diff(array_count_values($_POST), [1])){
    echo "variable cannot be same";
}else{
    echo "good";
}
```

You can test the code here if you want: https://3v4l.org/l15P0

As I commented to the other answer, array_unique is slow.
Comparing the two methods show a significant difference.
https://3v4l.org/NJIl5

Comment: yeah this is work too , i have a question. how to make echo 'good' if i have 2 same variable value blank ('')

Comment: @FikriF you can add an array_filter to the if(). Array_filter will remove all "" values. `if(array_diff(array_count_values(array_filter($_POST)), [1])){` https://3v4l.org/sdoBS

Answer (score 3):

I'd put all the values in array, remove duplicates using [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and compare their sizes:

```
$orig = array($a, $b, $c, $d);
$uniq = array_unique($orig);
if (count($orig) != count($uniq)) {
    echo "variable cannot be same";
} else {
    echo "good";
}
```

Comment: Quite a comprehensive solution

Comment: Keep in mind array_unique is a slow function only use it when you must. https://www.exakat.io/avoid-array_unique/